# Form is zoomed in on some computers

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, screen

Some people that use my program have a like zoomed in form. Has this anything todo with the .NET version they have or what's the problem. They don't have the same screen resolution.

[image]

Comment: zoom on a browser is a user specific setting, so it could be something they did. also, it looks like your site could possibly be using responsive design? if so, are the windows sized funny? maximize them on both computers and see what happens.

Comment: @mmeasor what are you trying to say?

Comment: @mmeasor OP tagged this as `winforms` so not browser based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely seems like a result of [DPI awareness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (available since Windows Vista).

The right thing to do is to make your app "fluid" and properly format itself for bigger content.

The easy way out is to disable DPI awareness. Your app will still be bigger, but it will be scaled as a whole instead of having every independent component scale by itself.

You can do so by adding the following in your app.manifest file:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
 ...
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>false</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
 ...
</assembly>
```

Comment: I tried this, but at Windows 8 it gives an error, and on Windows 7 it don't gives an error..

Comment: What's the error on Windows 8? Also, on Windows 7, when it looks scaled up, is DPI scaling enabled in the OS (Right-click desktop, Screen Resolution, Make text and other items larger or smaller. If it's on anything else than "Smaller" or 100%, DPI scaling is activated)?

Answer (score 1):

Have the users change their browsers zoom to 100%  It may be >100% and thus may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: it is tagged `winforms` so I'm assuming no browser involved

Comment: It's a c# application, has that something to do with browser zoom..?

Comment: if you are developing a desktop application - ie clients start an executable, written using `WinForms` then this has nothing to do with browser zoom. If you have developed a web app, which clients access with a web browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc) then browser zoom can effect what users see.

Answer (score 0):

The version of .NET should make no difference. The version of windows probably does, and also things like settings for high DPI screens, as blogged by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LivingAHighDPIDesktopLifestyleCanBePainful.aspx)

Comment: Is there a solution for this?

Comment: That depends. I think you should identify the worst case settings (speak to your users if you can) and somehow test yourself. Make sure your UI will scale sensibly.